# Instantiating a class when the first instantiation is still executing its static block

Tags: java

Let's say I have static block in a class that takes 5 seconds to be completed. Before this 5 seconds lapsed, a new instantiation of the same class is executed. What happens in this case? Is the second instantiation delayed until the first instantiation finishes? Does the static block acts as a 'synchronizer' of instantiations in this case? Are both instantiations executed in parallel?

P.D.
Pls refrain starting a discussing about whether a slow static block is bad.

Comment: "Does the static block acts as a 'synchronizer' of instantiations in this case" Yes, static blocks are synchronized (at least within each class loader).

Comment: Java static initializers are thread safe. See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.4.2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.4.2

See step 2:

> If the Class object for C indicates that initialization is in progress
>   for C by some other thread, then release LC and block the current
>   thread until informed that the in-progress initialization has
>   completed, at which time repeat this step.

And step 6:

> Otherwise, record the fact that initialization of the Class object for
>   C is in progress by the current thread, and release LC.
>
> Then, initialize the static fields of C which are constant variables
>   (§4.12.4, §8.3.2, §9.3.1).

and finally step 9:

> Next, execute either the class variable initializers and static
>   initializers of the class, or the field initializers of the interface,
>   in textual order, as though they were a single block.

As you can see, if multiple threads need to initialize the class at once, only one of them gets through. The others will wait until the succesful one completes its work. So your 5 second static initializer will run, and the other thread will wait until it completes before creating the instance.